# Can this point be a local maximum?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable and let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We generate the FINITE sequence $\{x_k\}_{k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}}$ in the following way:
>
> For each $k > 0$ take a $y_{k-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that a $t_k \in \mathbb{R}$ exists with
> $$f(x_{k-1}+t \cdot y_{k-1}) < f(x_{k-1})$$
> for all $t \in [0,t_{k-1}]$. Then $x_k = x_{k-1}+t_{k-1} \cdot y_{k-1}$.
>
> Can $x_n$ be a local maximum?

I would say yes, just consider the picture below: [image]

Could you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: But $n$ is at the opposite end from $0$? Also, you need to edit: You need to assume $t>0$.

Comment: A $t_k$ exists with a property that mentions $t_{k-1}$ but not $t_k$?

Comment: If the answer is yes, we ought to be able to give a specific example of $f$ and $\{x_k\}$ where it's true - maybe with $n=1$.